# Hover nav-bar sub nav should be visible

Tags: html, css, navbar

When I try to hover on PARK sub-nav it should appear but it doesn't and it should overlap on hero-slider.

**My code:**

```css
.subnav ul {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}


.nav-hover:hover .subnav {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li><a href="#"><img src="./assets/asset 0.png" alt=""></a></li>
          <li class="nav-part"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          <li class="nav-part nav-hover"><a href="#">Parks</a></li>
          <li class="nav-part"><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="subnav" id="subnav">
        <ul>
          <li>Link1</li>
          <li>Link2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**I want achieve the below output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> .subnav ul {}
> .nav-hover:hover .subnav {}
> ```

You have two errors. First, the `ul` is hidden but the hover attempts to change the display of `<div class="subnav" id="subnav">` which wasn't hidden. You need to either change the display of the `ul` or hide `.subnav` instead of the `ul`.

Second, `.subnav` is not a descendent of `.nav-hover`. You'll need to go up to either the first common sibling container or parent container and use the [`:has` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) to apply style to `.subnav`

```
.navbar:has(.nav-hover:hover) ~ .subnav ul { /* ~ general sibling combinator */
  visibility: visible;
}

.header:has(.nav-hover:hover) .subnav ul { /* descendent combinator */
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```css
.subnav ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.header:has(.nav-hover:hover) .subnav ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!-- Nav Bar -->

<div class="header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="./assets/asset 0.png" alt=""></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-part"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
      <li class="nav-part nav-hover"><a href="#">Parks</a></li>
      <li class="nav-part"><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="subnav" id="subnav">
    <ul>
      <li>Link1</li>
      <li>Link2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI , I am not able to take mouse on the sub nav its getting disappear .

Comment: @ShraddhaGupta Did you try the answer by Md. Rakibul Islam? I think it's a more practical solution to have the submenu nested inside, which doesn't rely on `:has()` and keeps the hover effect active.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. I also had to change the markup. Necessary details are written in comments.

```css
.subnav ul {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
}        

/* added codes =================================  */
.subnav{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
}

.nav-hover{
    position: relative;
}

.nav-hover:hover .subnav, .subnav:hover{
    visibility: visible;
}

.main-nav{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.main-nav li a{
    margin: 0 15px;
}
/* added codes =================================  */
```

```html
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="./assets/asset 0.png" alt=""></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-part"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li class="nav-part nav-hover">
                <a href="#">Parks</a>
                <!-- You need to keep it in the nav-hover container so that you can target it using CSS -->
                <div class="subnav" id="subnav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link1</li>
                        <li>Link2</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-part"><a href="#">What's New</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: It is invalid to have `div` as a direct child of `ul`. Perhaps it could be inside the `li` after the `a`? My answer shows that it doesn't have to be in the same container.

Comment: @TimR Thanks for pointing it out. I made the corrections :)